# Setting Cloud Composer Environment Variables with Special Characters via gcloud

Tags: environment-variables, gcloud, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to figure out how to create a Google Cloud Composer environment via `gcloud` and set environment variables with some special characters.

Example environmental variable:
API_URL=https://stuff.api.thing.com

Example of `gcloud` cmd I'm using:

```
gcloud composer environments create new-env-1 --location=us-central1 --airflow_configs=[core-dags_are_paused_at_creation=True] --env-variables=[API_URL=https://stuff.api.thing.com,env_type=dev] --node_count=3 --python-version=3 --image-version=composer-1.10.0-airflow-1.10.6 --network=projects/backcountry-data-team/global/networks/default
```

When running the example above, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.composer.environments.create) argument --env-variables: Bad value [[API_URL]: Only upper and lowercase letters, digits, and underscores are allowed. Environment variable names may not start with a digit.
```

This error is expected [based on the docs](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/environment-variables#gcloud).

I am, however, able to set environmental variables like the example if I go through the GCP Console. So shouldn't there be a way to do this via `gcloud`?

Comment: Don't include the `[` and `]` around the values

Comment: `--env-variables=API_URL=https://stuff.api.thing.com,env_type=dev` and `--airflow_configs=core-dags_are_paused_at_creation=True`

Comment: Pleased to hear it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better visibility for the community, I'm making the comments from @DazWilkin to an answer.

The `gcloud` command is expecting a comma separated *"list"* of key-value pairs; however, this differs to a `list` object on a programming language. In Python, for example, that `list` object would be something like this:

```
[1,2,3]
```

Instead the format expected for the `gcloud` tool is:

```
... the-flag=key1=value1,key2=value2
```

Which can also be seen on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/environment-variables#adding_and_updating_environment_variables) (under `gcloud` tab) as follows:

```
gcloud composer environments update ENVIRONMENT_NAME \
  --location LOCATION \
  --update-env-variables=KEY=VALUE,KEY=VALUE...
```

And as @DazWilkin states, this means that you don't need to include the `[` and `]` around the key-value pairs.

Leaving your command as next:

```
gcloud composer environments create new-env-1 --location=us-central1 \
  --airflow_configs=core-dags_are_paused_at_creation=True \
  --env-variables=API_URL=https://stuff.api.thing.com,env_type=dev \
  --node_count=3 --python-version=3 --image-version=composer-1.10.0-airflow-1.10.6 \
  --network=projects/backcountry-data-team/global/networks/default
```